# Is a plywood subfloor with outdoor carpeting glued on appropriate for a screened in porch

Tags: floor, plywood, carpet, porch, screens

We have a 20 year old screened in porch that had a plywood subfloor with outdoor carpeting tacked on.  We just pulled the carpet up and noticed blackish areas - mold?  The porch floor does get wet occasionally when heavy rain blows in through the screens.  We wiped the plywood with a bleach solution.  Installers are scheduled to come next week and glue down new outdoor carpeting.  My question is, should the plywood be treated, stained, or painted prior to gluing down new outdoor carpeting? The porch has glass window inserts for the colder months, but we leave the screens in for the summer so the carpet will get some rain on it.

I will include pictures of the porch with the old carpeting and with the carpeting pulled up.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what mold ? where ?

Comment: A little bit of sanding, some light stain and a good finish, that floor should look nice.

Comment: I would not put a carpet in the rain

Comment: I would replace this plywood with pressure-treated plywood at a minimum. It also strikes me odd that there is no place for water to drain or exit the porch. Is the porch sloped at all? If so, the lower end should provide some drain mechanism. Is the new outdoor carpet permeable? If so, I would not be gluing it down.

Comment: So you detect any soft spots or sagginess?

Comment: if it looks this good after 20 years i don't think you should be worried.